# How can I get the RequiredLength value of MinimumLengthValidator (related to Password in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-identity

I set the value MinimunLenghtValidator modifying the ApplicationUserManager class

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager() : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new DataContext()))
    {
        PasswordValidator = new MinimumLengthValidator(8);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve that value to use, for example, in the AccountViewModel validation (look at the entire StringLength line)

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = IWANTTHEVALUEHERE)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

Anybody could tell me how to get the value.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes require a constant value, so you would need to hard code it in your `StringLength` attribute. Alternatively, you can declare it as a public constant somewhere, probably on your `ApplicationUserManager` class

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public const int PasswordLength = 8;

    public ApplicationUserManager() : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new DataContext()))
    {
        PasswordValidator = new MinimumLengthValidator(ApplicationUserManager.PasswordLength);
    }
}
```

Then, in your view model you can reference the same constant

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = ApplicationUserManager.PasswordLength)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "New password")]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

The `UserManager<T>` class has a public `PasswordValidator` property which you can use to get access to the validator. The issue is that this property is an `IIdentityValidator<string>` so it can work with different types of validators. You need to cast this property to a `MinimumLengthValidator` in order to access the properties of that validator. You would need code similar to this:

```
int requiredLength = 0;
ApplicationUserManager manager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var validator = manager.PasswordValidator as MinimumLengthValidator;
if (validator != null)
{
   requiredLength = validator.RequiredLength;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, this is useful for my problem. Just by curiosity, do you know if it is possible to get the value of the MinimunLenghtValidator property?

Comment: @RLB: I updated the answer to show how you can get the value your looking for. You just won't be able to do it from within the `StringLength` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the properties from the membership class.

As example:

```
// System.Web.Security.Membership
Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength
```

You can also change the values in your web.config, this is mine:

```
 <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<!--<membership>
```